# use a SWC by 2 files that are loaded into a host swf file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, swc

I use flash cs6 (no flex no flashdevelop)
I have a main swf that loads into it 2 swf files. (actually it is much more then 2)
the two loaded files use symbols from the same SWC file.
what I want is to embed the swc to the main swf, and so the swc will be ready for the two loaded files.
but my problem is:
the loaded files are using  a class that refers to symbols inside the swc.
so when I export them (publish them as swf) I get an error if I dont embed the swc to each one of them.
is there a way around?

PS the swc is a huge file containing hundreds of .mp3 files that are needed for each of the loaded files, so I definately don't want to embed it to each of the loaded files.

Comment: What do you think about loading mp3 files by demand, without embedding them in swf files?

Comment: I am going to distribute it, and I want to protect my mp3 files

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of research it seems it is impossible to use swc by more then 1 file (without embeding it with each file that has to use it), so I will go with swf instead, as it can be external and can be used by all my loaded files. it is maybe less protected, but i will encrypt it, and when there is a need for one of the synbols, i will load the swf, decrypt it, and i will use getDefinitionByName to get to the symbols inside it. the disadvantage of this solution is that it will take me hours to create as linkage for each symbol.(and also the loading and decryption of the swf file might take some time) that is why I will still be glad to hear about a better solution.